# How do I display a list of images in uWP using MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I would like to share how to display a list of images in UWP using MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

In the Viewmodel you define the BitmapImages:
 (in this case 4 images called Tile0.jpg, Tile1.jpg, Tile2.jpg and Tile3.jpg located in the Assets folder in the project.

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> m_tileBitmaps;
    public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> TileBitmaps { get { return m_tileBitmaps; } }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        m_tileBitmaps = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                var bitmap =  new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Assets//Tile"+j.ToString() + ".jpg"));
                m_tileBitmaps.Add(bitmap);
            }
    }
}
```

In the view you can bind to the BitmapImages in this way:

```
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TileBitmaps}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

It took me a while to figure that out. I hope it helps someone.

Comment: Yep, that’s the way, although I would have used x:Bind and x:DataType in DataTemplate, defining a Model object for the ObservableCollection. It will help you if you have more than just one data type to display in every list item. Regards